# Проверка на ввод чисел

Tags: java, input

Как лучше всего организовать проверку на ввод отрицательного числа (они должны отсеиваться), чтоб это сильно не загромождало код, так как проверка в коде встречается не единожды, и чтоб не было постоянной конструкции if/else, после каждого считывания.

Comment: Добавте в вопрос ваш код.

Comment: Можно написать отдельный метод, который принимает `Scanner` (ну или с помощью какого класса вы считываете данные). В этом методе в цикле считывать числа (метод [`Scanner::nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--), проверять на отрицательность, если отрицательное, то выводить сообщение, что надо ввести положительное число, а если положительное, то возвращать число. Там где надо будет считать число будет очень изящно, в одну строчку: `int positiveInt = readPositiveInt(scanner);`